# preselect option with radiobuttonlistrow

Tags: yii, radiobuttonlist, yii-booster

I want to know how to preselect an option using the radiobuttonlistrow in yiibooster, I have read the yii documentation and in the case of radiobuttonlist it doest have an option to preselect the value but with yiibooster I can't find anyway to do this.

Any help will be highly appreciate

Gabriel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to know the option values before you render the View. For example in your view

```
<?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'attribute', array('0'=>'option1 ', '1'=>'option 2 ', '2'=>'option3 ')); ?>
```

Then before rendering this view in you action write

```
$model->attribute='1';
```

Then option1 will be selected when the raioButtonList is rendered.Similarly you can select other options as per your needs